# undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for Rails::Generator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on rails, suddenly rails server stops working. It's working fine and I have used following command [platform windows 7]

```
gem install -v=2.3.5 rails
```

And when I use `rails s`, it's giving the following error:

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:32:in `default_options': undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for Rails::Generator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:90:in `<class:Base>'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:85:in `<module:Generator>'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:48:in `<module:Rails>'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails_generator.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/rails:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby193/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from c:/Ruby193/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'

$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.5
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem, but it was the result of having the `gem rmagick`.

I ran the following:

```
gem uninstall rmagick 
gem cleanup
```

And then re-ran `bundle` in my stack and it worked for me again.

Answer (score 8):

I have solved this issue. Use following command and problem gone

```
 gem install rails
```

This will install updated rails and all thing working find again.

Answer (score 7):

Running `bundle exec rails s` worked for me.

My project was using Rails 3.x but when I ran `rails -v` I got `2.3.17` which is the version used by a project I worked on just before. Somehow installing this version must have be set as "default".

Could someone explain this ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and would love an explanation.

Comment: firstly use gem install rails the , rails s

Answer (score 4):

if you are using latest version of rails 3 or rails 4 then use `class_attributes` instead of `write_inheritable_attribute`, i.e.

```
class_attribute :variable_name
self.variable_name = value
```

instead of

```
write_inheritable_attribute(:variable_name, value)
```

Comment: This helped me to update a rails 2-style plugin for rails 3 and 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and it happens that I was in using the wrong ruby and gemset in rvm.

Answer (score 1):

(@jeremy-f and @alex-villa are on the right track to identifying the problem itself.)

The problem here is that the `rails ...` command in Rails version 2 is a generator, equivalent to `rails new ...` in Rails 3+. So `rails s` is a Rails 2 command to generate a new Rails 2 app called "s" (whereas most of us when we write `rails s` intend the Rails 3 usage, i.e. start a server!)

If you install a gem, it will usually install its binary in the path, so you should be able to cause this error by doing `gem install rails -v 2.3.15` then `rails s` as the OP says.

Three ways to fix it:

- `gem install rails` to install a newer version of Rails (you may have to specify a version >= 3.0)
- Run the app with `bundle exec rails s` (only if you have Rails 3 in your Gemfile)
- The usual way to run a Rails 2 project is simply `script/server`