# Redmine (1.4.7) error in executing server in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine, ruby-on-rails-2

While running redmine 1.4.7 in development mode using the command `rails s`, I have got error like below

```
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:32:in
 `default_options': undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for
 Rails::Generator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:90:in
 `<class:Base>'
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:85:in
 `<module:Generator>'
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:48:in
 `<module:Rails>'
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:6:in
 `<top (required)>'
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in
 `require'
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in
 `require'
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails_generator.rb:37:in
 `<top (required)>'
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in
 `require'
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in
 `require'
         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/bin/rails:15:in    `<top
 (required)>'
         from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load'
         from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I have spent about 2 hours for fixing it and got some references from this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078723/undefined-method-write-inheritable-attribute-for-railsgeneratorbaseclass)
and now am getting this error. How can I fix this??

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails_generator/generators/applications/app/app_generator.rb:7:in `<class:AppGenerator>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails_generator/generators/applications/app/app_generator.rb:7:in `<class:AppGenerator>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails_generator/generators/applications/app/app_generator.rb:7:in `<class:AppGenerator>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
undefined method `camelize' for "app":String
```

Comment: 1. Try `./script/server start` instead of `rails s` (you use 2nd Rails!). 2. But I think the main problem is Ruby 2.0 - try install ruby 1.9.3 or even 1.8.7

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this by using rvm

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following :

1. Install `"gem uninstall rmagick" and "gem cleanup"`
2. Run the server as `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: already  have done the above still am getting it and so i posted